# Drag and drop issues

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I need to do a drag and drop in my website. I have two options in which I must choose one to drag and drop in a square. My first problem is that when I drag one item, I cannot re drag it back and my second problem is that when I move the positions of my square and items, the drag and drop does not work. Can someone help me out here? or else is there a jQuery plugin that fit my concept?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<img id="drag1" src="images/cone.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img id="drag2" src="images/cup.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap the images in side a div exact same like the div that images going to be dropped.

the JavaScript part you mentioned seems ok. just wrap images inside a div

please give more details about the second prob. what do you mean bu changing the position of square and items

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; float:left; border: 1px solid; margin: 2px;"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; float:left; border: 1px solid; margin: 2px;">
        <img id="drag1" src="images/cone.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100" />
        <img id="drag2" src="images/cup.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am happy to say that I solved the second problem.